# Custom user defined file name format in c#

Tags: c#, filenames

The requirement is that a user can choose a file name format from predefined tags.

Example
InvoiceNo Date VendorName

if user chooses InvoiceNo-Date-Vendorname then the file name should be generated like: 001-20170512-ABCElectronics

if user chooses InvoiceNo-Date then the file name should be generated like: 001-20170512

if user chooses VendorName-InvoiceNo-Date then the file name should be generated like: ABCElectronics-001-20170512

format.Replace("InvoiceNo",generateNo()); 
Will .Replace first check if string exists and then executes the 2nd parameter? The 2nd parameter could be a long running method.

Should I first check if tag exists in the file format and then replace or just use .Replace method without checking?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?  Are you just asking how to concatenate strings in C#?  It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: `it.Replace("InvoiceNo", theInvoiceNumber).Replace("Date", theDate)...`

Comment: *"I need code example"* is not a question... What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck? Please have a look at the following Stack Overflow page and try to update your question accordingly: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AlexK. it seemed to me that it is a bigger deal but your code gave me some idea. I was drowned in more complex thoughts.

Comment: @bassfader. How can I achieve this in c#. is my question.

Comment: How does the user select these tags? If this is by text entry, it could be fragile and error-prone (typos, tag name changes, etc.). If this were a GUI program and it were up to me, I would present draggable items or a menu to the user for selecting presented tags, then build up the name using some combination of `StringBuilder` and an `IList` of enums representing your tags instead of just doing string replacement. Just a thought.

Comment: The idea is to display draggable tags that user can swap.

Comment: @Iffi: So basically you'd like someone to write your program for you and show you how it works?  Sorry, but you have misunderstood what Stack Overflow does.  You are encouraged to start here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @David, the experts who know c# code I think they know this is not a big task and I just needed an example for this simple task. and I did find my answer.

Comment: @Iffi: So you were just asking how to replace part of a string in C#?  In that case the question and subsequent comments were very unclear and misleading.  We're certainly here to help, and glad you found an answer.  But I recommend in the future explaining specifically the problem at hand and the question being asked, rather than describing unrelated things in your overall application.

Comment: @David: My question is probably not clear, but I was after a mechanism to generate a custom file name based on string not specifically about replacing strings in c#. I was already stuck on how to design that in the code. I was thinking a bit too much on the solution. My though was first to find the tag in the custom file format string and if existed then replace. But now I know a better mechanism.

Comment: input.Replace("InvoiceNo",generateInvo()); Will .Replace first check if string exists and then executes the 2nd parameter? The 2nd parameter could be a long running method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple way:

```
input = input.Replace("InvoiceNo",generateInvo());
input = input.Replace("Date",generateDate());
input = input.Replace("Vendorname",generateVendor());
```

this will change the first occurrence of those strings for the code you desire.
You can also do this in one line like `x.Replace(y0,y1).Replace(z0,z1);` if you wish.

Comment: Somehow I do not prefer to hardcode these "InvoiceNo", etc. I think I will get them form the database and then try to find and change in the file format chosen by the user

Comment: input.Replace("InvoiceNo",generateInvo()); Will .Replace first check if string exists and then executes the 2nd parameter? The 2nd parameter could be a long running method.

Comment: no it will not, it will replace in case "InvoiceNo" is found but ill confirm

Comment: For a more future-proof solution, it might be better to set up a dictionary of precomputed strings and iterate over it while doing all of the replacements.

Comment: test this --->  http://rextester.com/WALJM22691  as you can see, it will not replace if the index is not found